# Accept credit card/echeck payments

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card

I bill customers monthly for a service and would like them to be able to go to my website and pay by credit card or echeck.  I can do an integration with Authorize.net/ach direct/paypal/etc, but if there is something open source or some sample code to start with, it would be much easier.  I basically need the user to enter a name or number so I can identify the payment, and the amount they want to pay. The only thing I have been able to find, however, is shopping cart software that doesn't look like it does what I need. Is there anything I can use for this?  (Free is best)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is why a lot of people use PayPal and Google Checkout. They make some nice integration buttons you can use.

I've personally used Google Checkout a bit and their API is extremely easy to use. You can tailor the whole thing behind the scenes and then just kick the user over to Google to actually pay you for whatever "product" you generated on your site.

Additionally, you can send invoices to users directly from Google which will prompt them to go to Google CO to pay you.

I found their fees reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

Note that while the code may be freely available, you'll almost certainly be paying a transaction fee to a payment processing service; I recommend selecting one of those first, since it may impact heavily on how you go about coding it up.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably recommend against choosing the open source method for a few reasons;

1. Customer confidence in a "known" payment method --
2. Growing liability for electronic payments
3. Industry initiatives require diligent efforts to remain compliant. (Visa CISP, for example)
4. **Available** support when you need it.  (your reputation and good name is on the line)

Given that you would still require a merchant account to manage your transactions the net savings would be negligible, if at all.  But, of all the above items, I would recommend a reliable, proven, processor to limit your liability.

hope it helps.